# How to install and configure a DHCP server in NETWORK NAMESPACE

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a network namespace test.
Added physical interface eth0 to this namespace.
I have to run dhcp server on eth0 so that anyone connected through this port can get dynamic ip.

It is working fine if i don't create any namespace and use global.

But when i did this

```
$ ip netns exec test service isc-dhcp-server status

● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-05-22 03:06:56 IST; 2h 9min ago
     Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
 Main PID: 5315 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 22 03:06:56 PowerEdge-T20 sh[5315]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` contains `INTERFACES="eth0"`

and corresponding entry is present in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

Output of command:

```
$ ip netns exec test ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00


2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 48:ee:0c:bb:dc:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.1/20 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Whats the o/p of `ip netns exec test ip a`

Comment: inet 10.0.0.1/20 scope global eth0 valid_lft forever

Answer (score 0):

```
ip netns exec <NAME> <CMD>
```

So if you created a namespace called `foo` with a command like

```
ip netns create foo
```

After you configured the networking in that namespace you would start the service with a command that looks like:

```
ip netns exec foo service dhcpd start
```

Comment: Failed to restart dhcpd.service: Unit dhcpd.service not found.
But "ip netns exec test service isc-dhcp-server status" shows no interfaces present even though they are present